# pointwise convergence

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence

Am I right in saying that the sequence of functions $$f_n(x)=\displaystyle\frac{xn^\alpha}{e^{nx}\times\ln(n)}$$ converges pointwise to 0 $\forall{x}\in\mathbb{R}$?

Thanks for any help

Comment: You are right for $x \ge 0$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, take $x=-1$ then you get $\displaystyle \frac{-e^n n^{\alpha}}{\log(n)}\to-\infty$

Comment: oh dear of course, is it for all positive x then?

Comment: Yes, for $x\geqslant 0$ this is true since $\displaystyle \frac{1}{e^{xn}}$ dominates the rest of the terms.

Comment: cool thanks, that's what I thought just had a bit of a brain lapse. Thanks for the help

Comment: Then what can we say abou the convergence for $x<0$? That it diverges to $-\infty$?